# Overriding default ActiveRecord migration used to create tables in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

In our existing Rails 3 applications we use an overridden `migration.rb` file to customise the  table creation behaviour.

This was done in Rails 3 by placing our custom file in `lib/templates/active_record/model/migration.rb`, however it appears Rails 4 has changed the location used for these templates, and this override isn't picked up anymore (it uses the default ActiveRecord migration when creating tables).

I've had a look through the 4.1 ActiveRecord code but can't get the override to work again.

Does anyone know the correct location to place our custom `migration.rb` in a Rails 4 codebase?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

When you create a new model in Rails, the migration that is generated for you is based off the template found in (> 4.1.x) `activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb` in the [Rails gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb).

This has changed since Rails 3.2. In Rails 3.2 the template that was used was called `migration.rb` and was in the `activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates` directory of the [Rails gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/migration.rb).

In order to customise the generated template (add a custom SQL block that would be executed in the `change` method), we override this file by placing a modified copy of it in in our local code base under the `lib/templates/active_record/model` directory.

We customise it to add some application specific SQL to the end of the migration. In rails 3 this meant that any time you generated a new model, the resulting migration would auto-magically include our custom SQL at the end of the migration.

In our Rails 4 upgrade this custom migration isn't being used anymore, so we're getting vanilla migration files generated by rails, and are having to manually add the SQL each time.

I have tried following the same convention and placing the file in `lib/templates/active_record/migration/migration.rb` (and a variety of other locations) but the custom template is not being used by Rails when generating a migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 4.2.6 those paths are like this:

```
lib/templates/active_record/migration/migration.rb
lib/templates/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb
```

And the ultimate answer to this problem is to look into source code of Thor library, because all rails generators are based on it. This is how I found correct paths.

Go to `lib/thor/actions.rb` file and look for `find_in_source_paths` method and just add puts statement there. Whenever you run any generator you can see a list of all paths that are searched for templates. There are also other ways, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Late reply sorry :) Thanks for the answer - the first path didn't work, the second one did.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.1.4 this should go here:

```
activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb
```

Source:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration_rb.html

Comment: Thanks, but that's the wrong migration.rb. The file I want to override is in `activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates` in the Rails gem.